# Playing video from PC to TV through HDMI looks noticeably worse compared to playing directly from USB

Tags: networking, usb, video, display, hdmi

I have a non-smart LED TV.

And I have a uncompressed 1920x1080/60fps video which I copied to flash drive, plug it into the TV and play it, the result is really good.

However when I tried using my TV as PC monitor (with the same resolution of course) by linking both of them via HDMI cable, the quality looks noticeably worse when playing the same video.

It makes sense because the the video is processed by the PC (I use VLC in this case) in the 2nd scenario. So my question is, is playing video through HDMI always looks worse or it can look better or at least the same quality depends on the hardware linked to the TV?

Because I'm pretty sure my PC is strong enough to play Full HD video (i5 6600k & GTX 970).

Comment: Are you certain the TV on HDMI was running at 1920x1080? What did you notice about the quality difference, was it washed out, blurry, displaying artifacts, something else?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's set to 1920x1080. The video is kinda blurry, juddery, blocky, and artifacts when object is moving fast which is strange because when I play a fullscreen game, it looks pretty good.

Comment: Hmm... Does it look good on a standard monitor? I suggest you go through the TV settings - see if there's some special options for the HDMI input (some of them let you set different brightness/contrast/colour temps, etc.). Also perhaps HDCP-related... where are you playing the video from?

Comment: Yes it does look good on a standard monitor.

Comment: @warheat1990 Video it maybe? Would be easier to advise based on that.